# Free online AI/ML demos for grade 8-10 students

Tags: resource-request, secondary-education, artificial-intelligence

What are some free online AI/ML demos for grade 8-10 students?

I am a high school teacher, and I am exploring apps and games which will help students understand and appreciate the world of  Artificial  Intelligence and its applications and become AI-Ready.

I am looking for web browser-based applications only, including chrome web store; It need not be downloaded on the device, and cross-platform supported. For example, I found [Experiments with Google](https://experiments.withgoogle.com/) very helpful, which has hundreds of experiments. Similarly, [Microsoft AI demos](https://aidemos.microsoft.com/) has Machine Teaching, AI Route Planner, Text Analytics, Language Understanding, Video Indexer, Computer Vision, etc.

DeepPavlov, a free and open-source AI, has a [demo](https://demo.deeppavlov.ai/#/en/ner), which includes Entity recognition, Text QA, ODQA, Ranking, Intent classification, Insult detection, etc.

Please suggest more similar programs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems like you've already found quite a lot -- why are you seeking out more?  Do you have particular goals for things you're trying to demonstrate?

Answer (score 1):

Machine Learning for Kids is a resource for teaching ML to school age students that I have recently been playing around with. https://machinelearningforkids.co.uk/

It includes a range of projects that students can complete in Scratch, Python or App Inventor which range in challenge level.

There is also a book you can buy but it is possible to use the site without the book.

Comment: Welcome to [cseducators.se]. I hope we hear much more from you!